# Adding quick comment when voting to not re-open question?

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, comments, closed-questions

I would like to add a quick comment to a question that I'm voting to not re-open.

For example, a user has their question closed, and they worked on some significant edits to provide additional context.  However I voted for it to remain closed because in their header a python script was requested to assist in their question.  At no point prior to close and after their edits did they include a script example that they had in mind. I would want to tell them, that everything is good except for their question still not having a code sample.

I know I could always go to the question and add a comment, but I want to add a quick comment from the cozy confines of the Moderator review queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Reopen Review you will be in the Revision tab by default, which shows what has been changed in the post.

[image]

Clicking on the Question (Revised) tab will change the view slightly, into what the question now shows, including an Add Comment link at the bottom of the post (same as if you had opened the question directly).

[image]

This way you can add a comment and vote for Close/Reopen as you see fit.